# Android password/PIN reset via corporate e-mail without factory reset

Tags: android, mdm, password-recovery

I came across a scenario that user need to have a option(button) in lock down page to reset the Android password or PIN via corporate mail without doing factory reset. Based on the request via email Admin should have to enforce the default password or PIN in tablet remotely without Factory Reset. I understood from Google search I can do factory reset and set password policy using Device Admin. Did anybody faced this scenario before?

Highly appreciate any guidance in this!!!

Thanks :)

Comment: Is this a programming question?

Comment: Yes, I want to do through programmatically.